# Get Data to PDF Form from MySql Database using PHP/JAVA

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdf

I am working on project which need to get data from MySql database to PDF form.

Can anyone please guide how can I solve this problem?

I check internet for solution but I found I can create PDF form and get the data from DB to PDF form. My requirement are:

1. I have PDF form on server
2. I need to open that PDF form (using GUI)
3. Get the student record (student Id, FNAME, LNAME, etc) from the database and popluate in PDF form.

I have to make it work on multiple platforms (so ADO solution will not work as it for windows only)

Please guide me

Viral

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion using HTML and Java:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2006/jw-0410-html.html

Here is another option for converting from Java to PDF:
http://www.icesoft.com/products/icepdf.html

They both use open source software. There are many other commercial libraries out there for this sort of thing as well.

Comment: Thanks MaQleod. However, what if I have PDF template on server directory, I want to open PDF file from directory and select data from DB and put it into PDF file. 

The example shows I can convert HTML page to PDF but my PDF form is already design and need it in same way. 

Thanks for your help
Viral

Comment: Have a look at iText http://itextpdf.com/
It is a java library for creating and editing PDF files. It will allow you to fill out PDF forms using Java. I've used the C# port of this library and it has worked well.